# How does Windows determine the order of unconnected wireless networks shown?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

By which rules does Windows order the unconnected wireless networks in this system window (see the screenshot below)?

[image]

I thought Windows might order those networks by how good the signal from the network is. But then I noticed that at one point a network with only 1 signal bar was shown in the third place from the top.

Usually that network is shown further down the list.

Does anyone know the algorithm at work here?

Comment: It's entirely possible that there are no rules at play beyond "this network was seen first".

Answer (score 0):

It could be beacon reception time. A router sends a beacon every x seconds to notify everyone of it's presence. This is why it takes some time for you to see new networks.